# Installing ubuntu over a dual boot system

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04

I have already a dual boot system with Windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04, but it started to show some problems so i want to install ubuntu 16.04 in my notebook.

My question is: Can i download it from the website normally or does it need some other sort of proceeding (cuz i already have dual boot)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can just proceed as normal. Install it like you did when you first dual booted it. There will be options to dual boot again or normal install, and the installer will point out that you already have an Ubuntu installation on a partition, and ask for confirmation.